# Agreement of formulas for orthogonal projection onto a unit vector and non-unit vector

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, inner-products, projection

I must be doing something wrong.

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional inner product space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, $v \in V$, $W \subseteq V$ a subspace of $V$, $w \in W$, and $u= \frac{w}{\|w\|} = \frac{w}{\sqrt{\langle w,w\rangle}}$.

I want to prove that $\frac{\langle v,w \rangle}{\langle w,w \rangle} = \langle v,u \rangle$.

We see that $w = \|w\|u$, so the left hand side becomes

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\langle v,w \rangle}{\langle w,w \rangle} &= \frac{\langle v,w \rangle}{\|w\|^2} \\
&= \frac{\langle v,\|w\|u \rangle}{\|w\|^2}
= \frac{\overline{\langle \|w\|u,v \rangle}}{{\|w\|}^2} \\
&= \frac{\|w\|\overline{\langle u,v \rangle}}{\|w\|\|w\|} = \frac{\overline{\langle u,v \rangle}}{\|w\|} \\
&= \frac{\langle v,u \rangle}{\|w\|}
\end{aligned}
$$

But $\frac{\langle v,u \rangle}{\|w\|}$ is not always equal to $\langle v,u \rangle$!

Comment: Perhaps I'm not entirely understanding the statement you are trying to prove, but as a check, should this be true in the simple case of dot products in say 2D Euclidean space?  It might be useful to verify that things make sense in this simple case, where $v,w$ are just real vectors in this space.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, if $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$ scalars with the Euclidean inner product/dot product, then I want to prove that

$$\frac{\langle v,w \rangle}{\langle w,w \rangle} = \langle v,u \rangle$$

i.e.

$$\frac{v \bullet w}{w \bullet w} = v \bullet u$$

This should be true since $u$ is a unit vector with the same direction as $w$ and we can derive both sides as formulas for the projection onto the line spanned by $w$ (left hand side) or equivalently, the line spanned by $u$ (right hand side).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding to ad2004's comment helped me see that I did indeed make a mistake.

I wrote "I want to prove that $\frac{\langle v,w \rangle}{\langle w,w \rangle} = \langle v,u \rangle$" and found that $\frac{\langle v,w \rangle}{\langle w,w \rangle} = \frac{\langle v,u \rangle}{\|w\|}$, so what I was trying to prove is not always true.

My mistake was forgetting the full projection formula: $\left(\frac{\langle v,w \rangle}{\langle w,w \rangle}\right)w = v^{\|} = \langle v,u \rangle u$. So what I actually wanted to prove is $\left(\frac{\langle v,w \rangle}{\langle w,w \rangle}\right)w = \langle v,u \rangle u$.

Since $\frac{\langle v,w \rangle}{\langle w,w \rangle} = \frac{\langle v,u \rangle}{\|w\|}$, the left hand side becomes $\frac{\langle v,u \rangle}{\|w\|}w = \langle v,u \rangle u$ as desired.